# Putting a bit of Javascript in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to re-create this locally: http://jsfiddle.net/janpetras/wzBu8/
Granted, it shouldn't be that complicated, but I can't get it to work.

This is the code:

```
$(function(){
    var moneyEarned,yearlySalary,secondSalary;
    $("#startEarning").click(function(){
        moneyEarned = 0;
        var hourlySalary = $("#hourlySalary").val();
        if(hourlySalary.length > 0) {
            secondSalary = hourlySalary / 3600;
        } else {
            yearlySalary = $("#yearlySalary").val(); 
            secondSalary = yearlySalary / 7200000;
        }

        setInterval(updateMoneyEarned, 1000);
    });


    function updateMoneyEarned() {
        moneyEarned += secondSalary;
        $("#moneyEarned").html(accounting.formatMoney(moneyEarned));
    }
});
```

I want to put the Javascript code into a separate "script.js" file. I made the file, correctly linked to it in the HTML, I included jQuery and the accounting.js and everything, and it's not working, not updating.

I tried putting the code straight into the HTML and it's working if I do that, so clearly the problem is the way I make the script.js. I just copied/pasted that code, is there more to it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: make sure your js file is below the declaration of the jquery include

Comment: Show what your html looks like with the includes

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that @karthikr is pointing to the issue here. Make sure your script tag is placed after the script tag that's loading jQuery.

Comment: This is the html http://pastebin.com/2ymX1Vzt . The script is correctly linked after, don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you have to do things in order. You can't include this file if you didn't include jQuery before.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- your content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

After you have the correct order, you will be able to execute your scripts. If your `$(function(){ ... });` call doesn't work, try using it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

In your jsfiddle i can see that you were including accounting.js in css section:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/accounting.js/0.3.2/accounting.min.js"></script>
```

I moved it to the html section and it started working.

http://jsfiddle.net/GvAzM/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle works. I also moved it to the HTML file but I don't think that's the problem, the problem is that the javascript won't work, even though I link to the script.js separate file.